# How to minimize side bar when enter a spesific page?

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a sidebar.
When user enter the index page, I want to minimize the side bar. There is a button for that in sidebar:

```
<a class="mobile-menu" id="mobile-collapse" href="javascript:"><span></span></a>
```

How can I trigger this link when enter the home (index) page?

**sidebar.html**

```
<nav class="pcoded-navbar">
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar-brand header-logo">
            <a
               href="/" class="b-brand">
                <div class="b-bg">
                    <i class="feather icon-trending-up"></i>
                </div>
                <span class="b-title">HawkDragon</span>
            </a>
            <a class="mobile-menu" id="mobile-collapse" href="javascript:"><span></span></a>
        </div>


            <ul class="nav pcoded-inner-navbar">
                <li class="nav-item pcoded-menu-caption">
                    <label>Menü</label>
                </li>
                <li data-username="dashboard Default Ecommerce CRM Analytics Crypto Project" 
                    class="nav-item {% if 'index' in segment %} active {% endif %}">
                    <a href="/" class="nav-link "><span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="feather icon-home"></i></span><span class="pcoded-mtext">Anasayfa</span></a>
                </li>

                <li data-username="dashboard Default Ecommerce CRM Analytics Crypto Project"
                    class="nav-item {% if 'index' in segment %} active {% endif %}">
                    <a href="/" class="nav-link "><span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="feather icon-home"></i></span><span class="pcoded-mtext">Setup Wizard</span></a>
                </li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with window.location:

```
if (window.location.pathname == '/') {
    // your function to minify sidebar
}
```

window.location returns Location object with usefull properties.

Comment: I cannot understand how to use it. I want to run the link I show above when user enter the index page. How can I run this link in this function?